# What is the Message broker retry intval and how to configure

Tags: wso2, messagebroker, wso2-message-broker

I have used WSO2 Message Broker MB300 server for comiunicate each micro service. That is using Topic connection.

In the dash board "Durable Topic Subscriptions" section and "Number Of Messages Delivery Pending" column message showing as pending. That count getting increase. Any configuration for Message delivery delay or retry interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redelivery delay is introduced from MB 3.2.0 version which can be set as a system property. `System.setProperty("AndesRedeliveryDelay", "10000");` Also, maximum redelivery attempts can be set in broker.xml by setting the value as follows, `<maximumRedeliveryAttempts>10</maximumRedeliveryAttempts>`